# emacs org-mode: How to remove <colgroup> tag generated by HTML export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

Environment:
emacs 24.3 (9) for os x with org-mode version: 8.2.1.21

I used org-mode to convert org files with tables into html tables format. However, the html files always include the following snippets whenever a table exists:

```
<colgroup>
<col  class="left" />

<col  class="right" />

<col  class="right" />
</colgroup>
```

I have tried several ways to eliminate that snippet output but those  tags just won't go way; some include
M-x customize-variable
1. org-html-*
2. org-export-table-*
3. org-export-html-*
4. org-table-*

I can see that snippet may be generated by ox-html.el but I cannot nil that action.

I just want to have plain HTML tables exported from my org files. Nothings else. No extra default attribute, no other default HTML tags, no css, etc. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no customization options to remove `<colgroup>`.
But you can do this if you know that you don't want them at all:

```
(defun org-export-table-cell-starts-colgroup-p (table-cell info))
(defun org-export-table-cell-ends-colgroup-p (table-cell info))
```

Comment: That does the magic trick to remove <colgroup> tags but
    <col  class="left" />
     
    <col  class="right" />

    <col  class="right" />

are still floating around. How can I eliminate those <col> tags not in use? Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible short of rewriting `org-html-table`
function. Well, just commenting out an argument to
`org-html-close-tag`. But it's not a great fix, since you'll have to synchronize
your modifications with org-mode updates.